# Pandas data frame and SQL query

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm trying to translate the SQL query to pandas. However, after trying a lot I have now a knot in my head...

```
SELECT
 ID, Date1, Date2, Value
FROM
 data t1
WHERE
 t1.ID = 100 AND Date2 BETWEEN '2010-01-01 00:00:00.0' AND '2010-01-31 23:59:59.0' AND t1.Date1 =
 (
  SELECT
   max(t2.Date1)
  FROM
   data t2
  WHERE
   t2.Date1 <= '2010-02-01 00:00:00.0' AND t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.Date2 = t1.Date2
 ) 
ORDER BY
 t1.Date2
```

Does anyone have a clever idea?

Many Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "translate the SQL query to pandas"? Do you want to load the data into a dataframe?

Comment: Can you provide more detail like what was the initial query and what do you want to achieve(the problem statement)?

Answer (score 0):

You can load data by using the read_sql_query method.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_sql_query(your_sql_statement, your_db_connection)
```

Comment: Thanks. But that is not what I was looking for because to query in this way takes long. The way I'm looking for should be like df[(df['Date2'] >= '2010-01-01 00:00:00.0') & (df['Date2'] <= '2010-01-31 23:59:59.0') & ??????????? & df['Date1'] <= '2010-02-01 00:00:00.0' ?????????????

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. But that is not what I was looking for because to query in this way takes long. The way I'm looking for should be like

```
df[(df['Date2'] >= '2010-01-01 00:00:00.0') & (df['Date2'] <= '2010-01-31 23:59:59.0') & ??????????? & df['Date1'] <= '2010-02-01 00:00:00.0' ?????????????
```

Comment: So you want to translate sql oprations into pandas operations?

Comment: Google does not show much so you will probably need to write your own translator

Answer (score 0):

You don't show any example data, so an answer cannot easily be checked.

The inner part of your query

```
 SELECT
   max(t2.Date1)
  FROM
   data t2
  WHERE
   t2.Date1 <= '2010-02-01 00:00:00.0' AND t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.Date2 = t1.Date2
```

becomes

```
mask = df.Date1 <= '2010-02-01'
inner = df.loc[mask, :].groupby(['Date2', 'ID'], as_index=False)['Date1'].agg('max')
```

This DataFrame can now be joined with your initial `df`:

```
mask = (df.ID == 100) & (df.Date2 >= '2010-01-01 00:00:00.0') & (df.Date2 < '2010-01-31 23:59:59.0')
df.loc[mask, ['ID', 'Date2', 'Value']].merge(inner, on=['ID', 'Date2'])
```

Comment: Thanks. That is helping a lot. However, I got the error: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: At which point does this error occur? Please create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use smart logics to filter data from a dataframe.

So, the dataframe looks like this:

```
Date1               Date2               Value
01.03.2019 01:00    02.03.2019 00:00    0,824778017
01.03.2019 01:00    03.03.2019 00:00    0,235332219
01.03.2019 01:00    04.03.2019 00:00    0,0545149
01.03.2019 01:00    05.03.2019 00:00    0,088324545
01.03.2019 01:00    06.03.2019 00:00    0,011294991
01.03.2019 19:00    02.03.2019 00:00    0,184424959
01.03.2019 19:00    03.03.2019 00:00    0,610644963
01.03.2019 19:00    04.03.2019 00:00    0,777668521
01.03.2019 19:00    05.03.2019 00:00    0,922268093
01.03.2019 19:00    06.03.2019 00:00    0,654392958
02.03.2019 01:00    03.03.2019 00:00    0,388756252
02.03.2019 01:00    04.03.2019 00:00    0,561393704
02.03.2019 01:00    05.03.2019 00:00    0,761488545
02.03.2019 01:00    06.03.2019 00:00    0,831463861
02.03.2019 01:00    07.03.2019 00:00    0,981502269
02.03.2019 19:00    03.03.2019 00:00    0,277360792
02.03.2019 19:00    04.03.2019 00:00    0,502428364
02.03.2019 19:00    05.03.2019 00:00    0,241836513
02.03.2019 19:00    06.03.2019 00:00    0,118992825
02.03.2019 19:00    07.03.2019 00:00    0,584641587
03.03.2019 01:00    04.03.2019 00:00    0,236813627
03.03.2019 01:00    05.03.2019 00:00    0,53616114
03.03.2019 01:00    06.03.2019 00:00    0,959270138
03.03.2019 01:00    07.03.2019 00:00    0,856270711
03.03.2019 01:00    08.03.2019 00:00    0,537138196
03.03.2019 19:00    04.03.2019 00:00    0,298802098
03.03.2019 19:00    05.03.2019 00:00    0,850840681
03.03.2019 19:00    06.03.2019 00:00    0,268404466
03.03.2019 19:00    07.03.2019 00:00    0,472132954
03.03.2019 19:00    08.03.2019 00:00    0,189761554
```

My objective is the following:

`Date2` is given between `02.03.2019 00:00:00` and `07.03.2019 00:00:00`.

First: for given `Date2`, retrun `Value` where `Date1` is the latest date

```
Date1               Date2               Value
01.03.2019 19:00    02.03.2019 00:00    0,184424959
02.03.2019 19:00    03.03.2019 00:00    0,277360792
03.03.2019 19:00    04.03.2019 00:00    0,298802098
03.03.2019 19:00    05.03.2019 00:00    0,850840681
03.03.2019 19:00    06.03.2019 00:00    0,268404466
03.03.2019 19:00    07.03.2019 00:00    0,472132954
```

Second: for given `Date2`, return `Value` where `Date1` does not go beyond a specific date

```
Date1               Date2               Value
01.03.2019 19:00    02.03.2019 00:00    0,184424959
02.03.2019 01:00    03.03.2019 00:00    0,388756252
02.03.2019 01:00    04.03.2019 00:00    0,561393704
02.03.2019 01:00    05.03.2019 00:00    0,761488545
02.03.2019 01:00    06.03.2019 00:00    0,831463861
02.03.2019 01:00    07.03.2019 00:00    0,981502269
```

My approach is to filter first `Date2` and then `Date1`

```
is_date2 = (df ['Date2']> = '02.03.2019 00:00:00 ') & (df [' Date2 '] <'07.03.2019 23:59:59')
df = df.loc [is_date2]

is_date1 = (df ['Date1'] <= '07.03.2019 19:00:00 ') & ... ???
df = df.loc [is_date1]
```

The answer from JoergVanAken is helpful, but has not yet reached my goal.

You can also interpert `Date1` as a forecast date and `Date2` as a value date

Thanks in advance